# How can I override (or ignore) row style class in column?

Tags: css, primefaces, datatable, styles

I applied `rowStyleClass` on my DataTable which uses following by the condition.

```
<style>
  .deleted {
    color: darkgray;
    text-decoration: line-through;
  }
  .normal {
  }
</style>
```

And I want last two columns don't follow the rule but none of following work.

```
<p:dataTable
  rowStyleClass="#{placementsController.started(placement) ? 'started' : ''} #{empty placement.deleted ? '' : 'deleted'}">

    <!-- other columns here -->

    <p:column style="width: 60px; text-align: center;">
      <p:commandLink id="deleteLink" actionListener="#{placementsController.delete(placement)}" update="placementsTable">
        <h:outputText value="#{empty placement.deleted ? 'delete' : 'undelete'}" style="text-decoration: none !important;"/>
      </p:commandLink>
    </p:column>

    <p:column style="width: 50px;text-align: center; text-decoration: none !important;">
      <p:commandLink id="cloneCommand" action="#{placementsController.clone(placement)}" update="placementsTable">
        <h:outputText value="clone"/>
      </p:commandLink>
    </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: @Kukeltje This is a PrimeFaces specific question. Thanks.

Comment: @Kukeltje You don't know `p:dataTable/@rowStyleClass`, do ya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work for me:

```
.deleted > td:nth-last-child(1), .deleted > td:nth-last-child(2) {
    /* put the normal style here */
    color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but you **know** css... and specificity like I suggested to the OP in my first (now removed by me) comment.

Comment: Yea I guessed you had suggested css